# Use stored procedures inside CYPHER statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was able to install apoc stored procedures on neo4j 3.0 server and it works.

However, I want to be able to call procedures insider CYPHER statements.

In particular, I'm trying to make this query work:

```
create (u:User {dateCreated: apoc.date.parseDefault('2015-03-25 03:15:59','s')})
```

Can anyone show me the way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the procedure and yield the value to supply to your create:

```
call apoc.date.parseDefault('2015-03-25 03:15:59','s') yield value
create (u:User {dateCreated: value})
```